# Avoiding apply in pandas rolling for "rolling cummax"

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

i want to use groupby rolling for computing the trailing cummmax for timeseries, like

```
import time
import pandas as pd


df_example = pd.DataFrame({"value": np.random.normal(1500), "group": 1500 * ["A"]})
t = time.process_time()
df_example["value"].rolling(100).apply(lambda x: x.cummax().max(), raw=False)
elapsed_time = time.process_time() - t
print(elapsed_time)
```

This is doing what I expect, i.e. computing the rolling cummax, but I fail to find an implemetation avoiding the combination of groupby and apply which is known to be slow- takes 0.75 sec on my computer for this example.

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: Do you need `df["timeseries"].rolling(h).cummax()` ?

Comment: Rather than the weasel words "is known to be extremely slow" can you post a sample input series (i.e. the code to generate one) which demonstrates this slowness, and tell us how long it takes on your machine so we can try to optimize it?

Comment: ```df_example["value"].rolling(100).max()``` (it returns exactly the same as your code - just 1000x faster ;) ) ```rolling(...)``` already does the cumulative part for you...